# How to properly make a div be at least screen height and expand to fit content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make page segments that are at least screen height, but able to expand if the content is too much for that height. The below snippet partially works but the inner panel2 div is not functioning properly, and its height = 100% is not making it fill its parent div when its content doesnt fill the screen (the second div).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel1{
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px orange solid;
}

.panel2{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel1">
  <div class="panel2">
    aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel1">
  <div class="panel2">
    aaa aaa 
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i get this to work properly, with the inner panel being able to fill the height of the parent?